# What is name of this 1927 town in Missouri?

Tags: palaeography, 1920s, missouri

I have a death certificate:

- https://www.sos.mo.gov/images/archives/deathcerts/1927/1927_00034802.PDF

With an informant, George A Plank Jr. and I'm unable to read the town he resides in within Missouri:

[image]

He used to live in Independence, Missouri but has moved here.

What is the name of the town?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The handwriting isn't great (and it hasn't come through well on the pdf copy), but the Address is given as "**Independence MO**".

The downstroke of the J of "Jr" crosses the last "e" of "Independence".

I've taken he liberty of removing the name and indicating each letter in red above the script here:

[image: Address]